# SmallInt vs Date in MySQL - Performance, Flexibility and Size

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a table that stores data, actually counter, for products for each week.

Example:

```
 id = 1
 productId = 195
 DateTime = 01/07/2012
 Counter = 0
```

My question to you is about database storage space, query flexibility and performance.

Instead of the DateTime column, I thought about using a SmallInt 'WeekNumber' column.

I will decide on the Date that the weeks start (base date). Let's say 10/10/2012.

For each product and for each week, there will be a row that represents the total of something that I count on a daily basis (ie. Pageviews for a specific product page).

From What I'v eread:

Date column is 4 bytes

SmallInt is 2 bytes

I want to save as much space as possible, but I want to be able to query the database base on range of dates (august 2012 to September 2013), specific week in a specific year, etc.

Is this approach to the schema is good, or I will find myself having problem with poor SQL performance, Query flexibility, indexes, etc.

Comment: This sounds like really pointless micro-optimization. Will you have millions or billions of records so that the saved space would actually matter? And even then - do you have a *real* storage space issue to fight? I'd say just use a proper date and be done with it

Comment: quite, I have 50GB limit. Have 2000 products (rows) each week. I need to know that I won't pass it and the other aspect of performance and query convenience, indexes, etc.

Comment: But with 2000 rows each week, you are looking at a savings of 4 kilobytes per week, 208 kilobytes per year. It would take ten years to save one Megabyte. Ten thousand years (approximately) to save one Gigabyte.

Comment: with 16 bytes total, I look for around 125MB / mo, If I calculates it right and for 14 bytes it's 110MB /mo. however, I'm considering adding the counter per day, So it might be crucial.

Comment: Hmm, still. I guess you could use a smallint and start counting days from a specific date, but you'd be giving up a lot of convenience and speed for this. If you add it per day, maybe consider some other way to prevent filling up your space - e.g. archiving older days to a local db.

Comment: Good idea, I will only remember the last week data for days. More practical and fits my application needs. Other queries will be according to weeks, month and years. Thanks

Comment: I can also drop the id, use both the datetime and productid as primary keys, right?

Comment: @IdanShechter you could use the Date/ProductID as the PK and forget about the id column, that's right.... Can I ask how your 50GB limit is imposed?

Comment: Question is been answered. You all been very helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this table has no child tables (no foreign keys referencing it), to conserve space, you might consider omitting the surrogate primary key `(id)`, and instead use a composite key `(productId,date_)` as the primary key. (From what you describe, it sounds as you are going to want to have the combination of those columns as UNIQUE, and both of those columns as NOT NULL.

If what you want to store is a "week" identifier rather than a DATE, there's no problem on the database side of things, as long as your queries aren't wrapping that column in an expression to get a DATE values to use in predicates. That is, for performance, your predicates are going to need to be on the bare "week identifier" column, e.g.

```
WHERE t.product_id = 195 AND t.week_id >= 27 AND t.week_id < 40
```

Predicates like that on the bare column will be sargable (that is, allow for an index to be used.)  You do NOT want to be wrapping that `week_id` column in an expression to return a DATE, and use WHERE clause on that expression.  (Having expressions on the literal side of the comparison is not a problem... you just don't want them on the "table" side.

That's really going to be the determining factor of whether you can use a `week_id` in place of a DATE column.

Using a "period id" in place of a DATE is fairly straightforward to implement for periods that are whole months.  (It's also straightforward for "days", but is really of less benefit there.)  Implementing this approach for "week" periods is more complicated, because of the handling you need for a week that is split between two years.

Consider, for example, that the last two days of this year (2012) are on Sunday and Monday, but Tuesday thru Saturday of that same week are in 2013. You'd need to decide whether that's two separate weeks, or whether that's the same week.

But the 1-byte savings (of SMALLINT vs DATE) isn't the real benefit. What the "week_id" column gets you (as I see it) is that you have a single id value that identifies a week. Consider the date values of `'2012-07-30'`, `'2012-07-31'`, `'2012-08-01'` they all really represent the same week. So you have multiple values for the week, such that a UNIQUE constraint on `(product_id,date)` doesn't really GUARANTEE (on the database side) that you don't have more than row for the same week. (That's not an insurmountable problem of course, you can specify that you only store a Sunday (or Monday) date value.)

---

In summary,

To conserve space, I would first drop that surrogate `id` column, and make the combination of the product_id and the DATE be the primary key.

Then I would *ONLY* consider changing that DATE into a SMALLINT, if I could GUARANTEE that all queries would be referencing that bare SMALLINT column, and NOT referencing an expression that converts the SMALLINT column back into DATE.

Comment: That's a very good answer, and I've learned a lot from it. Thanks.

Comment: @Idan: I've been right where you are, with a large number of rows and wanting to pack as many rows as possible into as few blocks as possible.  We've implemented a similar `period_id` column for monthly tables, not to conserve space, but primarily because the application developers wanted it because it's easier for the application to grab a consecutive 12-months. But being easier for the app wasn't really enough of a reason, the deciding factor was a single unique integer value to identify a period. (MySQL doesn't have declarative constraints that ensure e.g. a DATE ends with '-01'.)

Answer (score 3):

Consider the sacrifice and complication you're going to make in order to save <s>2 bytes</s> **one byte**....

In order to use the `smallint` you're going to pass every call to the data through a function to get its "week number" starting from your own arbitrary date.... This is neither more performant nor more clear.

The query is, likewise, not as flexible because each one will need to compare based on your magic "starting date" rather than just a date compare/group. Your queries will likely not be SARGable and will probably be **slower**

**EDIT:** From your comments you have a hard limit of 50GB.... that's a lot of space for an aggregation DB like you're discussing. You're inviting undue stress and loss of sustainability by complicating this.

According to MySQL, the `DATE` type is only 3 bytes compared to the 2 bytes for the `SMALLINT`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/storage-requirements.html

You are, therefore, going to save **one byte** per row (you say 2000 per week)... so let's say 2KB per week, 104 KB per year.....

Comment: Can I use the Date and ProductId as primary keys and drop the id column?

Comment: OK, thanks a lot for your time and my newbie questions. Question answered.